# Update with ajax an object in a JSP page

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jsp

In my JSP page i have an accordion list (I use Bootstap 3)  and inside of each list there is some text and a Delete button. When then user presses the delete button, that particular node of the list is deleted. To build the accordion list, I import to the JSP an ArrayList object, which contains the text i want. So i have:

```
//myNotif is the imported object
ArrayList<MyNotifications> myNotif= (ArrayList<MyNotifications>(session.getAttribute("myNotif"));

//here i build the accordion list
<div class="row">
 <div class="col-md-7">
   <div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
      <%int i=0; for(MyNotifications notiff:myNotif ) { %>
      <div class="panel panel-default">
          <div class="panel-heading">
               <h4 class="panel-title">
                    <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse<%=i%>">
                    Notification <%=i%></h4>
           </div>
           <div id="collapse<%=i%>" class="panel-collapse collapse ">
                <div class="panel-body">
                     <%=notiff.getNotification()%> //method that returns text
                     <p><a onclick="DeleteNotification()" class="btn  btn-primary btn-study-right fat-btn " role="button">Delete</a></p>
                 </div>
                </div>
         </div>
         <%i++;}%>
    </div>                
  </div>
</div>
```

Now I want to inform the servlet for the delete action, and update the node. So i have coded this in ajax

```
<script>
   function DeleteNotification(){
      var xmlhttp;
      if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
      {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
          xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
      }else{// code for IE6, IE5
                xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
           }

      xmlhttp.open("GET","MyServlet?action=DeleteNotif",true);
      xmlhttp.send();

   }
</script>
```

which works, I mean the serlvet is updated and it update the object myNotif. But I don't know how to refresh this part the jsp only..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But I don't know how to refresh this part the jsp only..

At this point its no longer a JSP, since its been sent to the client and is now just regular HTML. So you would do this in Javascript with DOM operations.

But you are missing one big part of Ajax, setting a response handler, which points to a function:

```
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = ajaxSuccessFunc; //function name can be whatever you want, you must define the function
xmlhttp.send();
```

Then you define your response handler, and make it do something with the response you received from the server, like overwriting the innerHTML of a particular element on the page:

```
function ajaxSuccessFunc()
{
    if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4)
    {
        if (xmlhttp.status == 200)
        {
            var data = xmlhttp.responseText;
            document.getElementById('accordion').innerHTML = data;
        }
    }
}
```

I used to manually code my Ajax like you're doing, but if you use [JQuery](http://jquery.com/) (a popular javascript library) the code becomes this short: (All the stuff for various browser differences is handled for you.)

```
 function DeleteNotification()
 {
         $.ajax({
             type : "GET",
             url : "MyServlet",
             data : {
                 'action' : 'DeleteNotif'
             },
             success : function(data)
             {
                 $("#accordion").html(data);
             }
         });
 }
```